# jquery slider based on select form

Tags: jquery, mysql, jscript

I have already made a select form it is loading from mysql.
I would like to change it with jquery slider.
My problem is i haven't find a slider which is
only use the the values that already exist in the mysql.

Is there a way to convert my select form into jquery slider?

Comment: Post some relevant code or make a fiddle so that we can help you better.

Comment: Just found this solution:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update-jquery-ui-slider-from-a-select-element-now-with- aria-support.html

thank you very much your time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on DOM ready, manipulate the `select` using javascript/jquery, then apply the slider.